# In R, How do you extract columns when you don't know how many columns there are in all datasets?

Tags: r, sum, extract, multiple-columns

I have a list of 52 datasets and I am trying to get column sums for a specified number of columns from each dataset and export it to a new dataframe. I know I want to sum everything in column 9 and afterwards but the total number of columns varies between each dataset. ("locs" is my list of dataframes)

Here is what I have tried using a for loop:

```
summaryofsums <- vector("list",1) #empty vector

for (df in 1:length(locs)){
  newdf <- df[, colSums(df!= 0) > 0] #get rid of all columns that have only 0s
  newdfsum <- colSums(newdf[,9:length(newdf)])  
  summaryofsums[i] <- newdfsum
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in colSums(df != 0) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

> version
> _
> platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
> arch           x86_64
> os             darwin15.6.0
> system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
> status
> major          3
> minor          5.3
> year           2019
> month          03
> day            11
> svn rev        76217
> language       R
> version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
> nickname       Great Truth

Thank you!!

Comment: The number of columns in a dataframe is returned with the `length` function which you seem to have used appropriately. The only thing missing from your loop would appear to be an initialization of `summaryofsums`. You should _always_ post the complete text of any error messages. So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sapply` :

```
sapply(locs, function(df) {
  newdf <- df[, colSums(df!= 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0]
  colSums(newdf[,9:ncol(newdf)], na.rm = TRUE)  
}) -> result

result
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that you are doing a 1:length() on a list but not calling the item in that list, for instance, with your way you would want to do:

```
for(i in 1:length(locs)){
 locs[[i]] #where this is now df in your code
 ....
}
```

An easier way to do it, I think, would be:

```
 # Create your (I assume) variable to hold your sums
 0 -> summaryofsums
 
 # Loop through each dataframe and get the sum of everything after 9th column
 # This will produce a list with each entry the sum of each column after 9 per
 # dataframe
 for(df in locs){
  df[, colSums(df) > 0] -> newdf
  sum(colSums(newdf[, 9:ncol(newdf)])) + summaryofsums -> summaryofsums
  }
```

This will simply create a variable `summaryofsums` that is the sum of all the values in all columns after and including the 9th column of all datasets.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an error for the brackets? 
"unexpected '}' in:
"summaryofsums <- sum(colSums(newdf[, 9:ncol(newdf)]) + summaryofsums
}"

Comment: Fixed! Sorry - there was a missing ")".